# iOS: potential leak of data: CFDataGetBytePtr

Tags: ios

I am getting that data from an CGImageRef and then setting a structure I created to point to this data:

```
        CFDataRef data = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef));
        const UInt8 * imageData = CFDataGetBytePtr(data);
        myPix->data = (l_uint32 *) imageData;
```

However I am getting an memory leak warning when I do Product -> Analyze.

I think the reason is because I don't do CFRelease(data). However if I do that myPix -> data gets modified. How can I get rid of the memory leak warning but get it to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're just assigning a pointer there - casting away const (undefined behavior if you write to it), and disposing of the owner (freeing the allocation assigned to `data` -- also undefined behavior when you read or write to that memory region).

if you want a mutable copy of that data, you must create your own mutable copy. the you can safely call `CFRelease(data)`.

there are two immediate ways to create a mutable copy:

1) using `malloc`

- Create a new allocation using `malloc`
- then copy the buffer from `data` to your buffer
- then assign the buffer to `myPix->data`
- when you are done with the allocation `myPix->data` references, call `free(myPix->data);`

2) Create a mutable copy of the CFData.

```
CFMutableDataRef mutableData = CFDataCreateMutableCopy(0, 0, data);
myPix->data = (l_uint32 *)CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(mutableData);
```

when you are done with the allocation `myPix->data` references, call `CFRelease(mutableData);`

Comment: If I understand the OP question correctly, then `CFDataGetBytePtr` is in fact allocating memory that you are responsible for deleting. I'm having same issue. What's challenging is that I cannot find any documentation that indicates it is allocating memory. If I don't release, I also get a memory leak, but how would one know if a particular `CF` function is in fact creating memory that you are responsible for?